# How to write DataFrame-friendly functions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Recently I've been making the switch from using numpy's `ndarray` to pandas' `DataFrame` for my data analysis needs. I've noticed that numpy functions seem to accept `DataFrame` objects in place of `ndarray` without issue. However, when I try to use many of my existing functions written to operate on `ndarray`, they often fail on indexing operations, broadcasting etc. and I am forced to pass the underlying `ndarray` with `df.values`.

Is there some standard way or set of guidelines to make a function compatible with `DataFrame`? How do numpy functions accomodate for both types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resorted to digging around in the numpy source code and found that many functions simply convert the input to `ndarray` first using functions such as [`asarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html) or [`asanyarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asanyarray.html).

```
def numpyFunction(x, *args, **kwargs):
    x = np.asanyarray(x)
    ...
```